# An iterative argument involving $f(n + 1) - f(n) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences, induction

I am working with an argument involving an inequality of the form:
$$ f(n + 1) \leq f(n) + C (f(n))^{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}} \qquad(\ast)$$ 
where  $f$ is a positive function, $\gamma > 0$ and $C > 0$. It is know (but no proved explicitly) that $(\ast)$ leads to the bound
$$ f(n) \leq n^{\gamma} \quad( \forall n > n_0 )\qquad (\ast \ast)$$ for a certain $n_0$ to be choosen.

My question is: How to prove $(\ast \ast)$, being that we have $(\ast)$ ? My failed attempt was to use a telescopic sum 
to obtain $$f(n + \ell) - f(n) \leq C \sum_{k = 0 }^{ \ell - 1}(f(n + k))^{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}}$$ but, this does not lead to $(\ast \ast)$ straight.

Comment: Your conclusion is false. For example, let $\gamma\geq 1$ and $C:=\gamma 2^\gamma$. Then the function $f(n):=2n^\gamma$ satisfies $(\ast)$, but it does not satisfy $(\ast\ast)$. On the other hand, it is not hard to show that $(\ast)$ implies that $f(n)\leq cn^\gamma$ for all $n$, where $c:=\max(f(1),(C/\gamma)^\gamma)$.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea in such problems is to use differential analogue. Here we consider the inequality $$f'(x)\leqslant C f(x)^{1-\frac1\gamma},$$
that rewrites as $(f(x)^{\frac1\gamma})'\leqslant \frac{C}\gamma.$
This suggests to consider the function $g(x)=f(x)^{\frac1\gamma}$ (in general you consider the new function which varies less or more "linearly").
Return to the initial inequality with the sequence. Denote $g(n)=f(n)^{\frac1\gamma}$. We have
$$
g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n+1)^{\frac1\gamma}-f(n)^{\frac1\gamma}=(f(n+1)-f(n))\cdot \frac1\gamma\cdot \theta^{\frac1\gamma-1},
$$
for some $\theta$ between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$, here we use [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) . This is bounded from above by a constant, as follows from the initial inequality. It implies that $g(n)=O(n)$.

Your claim that $g(n)\leqslant n$ for large $n$ is unfortunately not true in general, take $f(n)=2n^\gamma$ and large $C$.

Comment: I beat you by $21$ seconds! See my comment above.

Comment: I spent these 21 seconds to realizing that mean value theorem belongs to Cauchy, not to Lagrange as I was sure all my life.

Comment: Wait, it is Lagrange's mean value theorem, isn't it?

Comment: It seems that Cauchy's MVT generalizes Lagrange's MVT: https://www.math24.net/cauchys-mean-value-theorem/

Comment: Dear @FedorPetrov, thank you for your reasoning. But,  I do not understand very well the phrase "This is bounded from above by a constant, as follows from the initial inequality"  From the initial inequality we have $f(n + 1) - f(n) \leq C (f(n))^{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}}$. Thus, $ g(n + 1) - g(n) \leq \frac{C}{\gamma}  (f(n))^{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}} \theta^{\frac{1}{\gamma} - 1} $. How this fact leads to  conclusion that $g(n) = O(n)$ ?

Comment: @Marcelo if $f(n+1)<f(n)$, the difference $g(n+1)-g(n)$ is bounded from above by 0. Otherwise $f(n+1)\in [f(n), 2f(n)] $ for large enough $f(n) $, and $\theta$ in the same interval, so $g(n+1)-g(n)$ is bounded from above by a constant.

Comment: Well, if $\gamma<1 $ and $f(n) $ is close to 0, it may appear that $f(n+1)$ is very large. But I guess this is not what you mean, and some not mentioned in OP restrictions forbid this.

Comment: @GHfromMO this is what I was thinking, but wiki does not mention Lagrange at all.

Comment: I think Wikipedia is right. What Lagrange stated in 1801 is not what we call Lagrange's MVT today. Cauchy published this theorem in 1823 and also what we call Cauchy's MVT, see slides 75-80 in https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf

Comment: Dear @FedorPetrov, it is clear that we have two cases. If $f(n+ 1) - f(n) \leq 0$ then $g(n + 1) \leq g(n)$, but we can not say that $g(n) \leq g(1)$ because $g$  does not have monotonicity property. On the other hand, if $0 < f(n + 1) - f(n) $, is not clear that $f(n + 1) - f(n ) < f(n)$ for $f(n)$ large enough. Remark that if we have this property, the R.H. S of your solution is bounded by $\frac{1}{\gamma} (2 f(n))^{1/\gamma}$, which is not bounded.

Comment: Two cases are considered for proving that $g(n+1)-g(n)\le C$. After this is proved, we sum up such inequalities for concluding that $g(n) =O(n) $.